# Input (as a condition) terminates when the value is entered

Tags: c++, for-loop, input, terminate

Goals:

1. Write a program where you first enter a set of name-and-value pairs, such as Joe 17 and Barbara 22.
2. For each pair, add the name to a vector called names and the number to a vector called scores (in corresponding positions, so that if names[7]=="Joe" then scores[7]==18).

Problems:
Input (as a condition) terminates when the values are entered.

Questions:
Is there a way to avoid it?
Why does it terminate?
Is there a more effective approach?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<int> values;
std::string name;
int value;

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; std::cin >> name >> value; i++){
        names[i] = name;
        values[i] = value;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Upon what condition *is* the loop supposed to terminate?

Answer (score 2):

Your vectors are empty. You cannot use `operator[]` to access any element, because there is none. The "termination" is most likely a segmentation fault (your OS stops your program, because it tries to access memory that doesn't belong to it).

You can append to your vectors using [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method:

```
int main(){
    //you don't need any counter, so it's easier to use while loop:
    while (std::cin >> name >> value) {
        names.push_back(name);
        values.push_back(value);    
    }
}
```